# QGIS Export project to DXF loses attribute data in AutoCAD

Tags: qgis, autocad

I have managed to export my QGIS project (with more than 10 layers) to AutoCAD DXF format.

[image]

The problem is, that I cannot find the attribute table data in AutoCAD.

Amidst a few options, which are here:

https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/civil-3d-forum/how-to-transfer-shapefile-attributes-from-gis-into-autocad/td-p/8442245

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/34156

They advise typing the command: `MAPCONNECT, MAPWSPACE`, or `MAPIMPORT`.

Unfortunately, none of them work in the AutoCAD Lite version.

How can I transfer the attribute table along with my QGIS project without splitting it into separate layers?

UPDATE:

I tried also via GDAL, but I have the following error:

**DXF layer does not support arbitrary field creation, (field name) not created**

[image]

Comment: Why is splitting into several layers unwanted, if it works? Have you had a look at the spatial manager for CAD?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alfred NESWADBA answer from your first link state :

> Polylines in AutoCAD does not have more informations than AutoCAD has
> for them, like layer, linetype, ... And as long as you only have
> polylines from AutoCAD they can't have any more informations, that is
> one difference between CAD and GIS.
>
> In Map3D you might use ObjectData, with that option you can create
> ObjectDataTables in your DWG-file and then assign ObjectDataRecords to
> each polyline. But that is by far not so easy to edit and handle as
> the SHP dataset is.

So if you only have AutoCAD Lite you can't get attribute, you need Map3D or Civil3D to access or import shapefile.

(ESRI give these instruction to [export attribute values to AutoCAD block attributes](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/cad/exporting-attributes-to-autocad-block-attributes.htm), I don't know if this would work with QGIS export to CAD but you may try it...)